# Access SQL, append query breaks when using ODBC/PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access, odbc

I'm designing a web interface for my clients database (A .mdb MS Access file). I'm using an ODBC driver to connect to it and the odbc_ functions provided by PHP.

My problem is access's 'append' queries. From what I gather, it's just inserting more rows, but something is breaking the query from executing:

```
INSERT INTO test ( TITLE, [LEVEL], UNITID, TITLEM, COHORTPLUSOPTIONS )
SELECT \"OPTION ONLY\" AS Expr, Units.LEVEL, UnitOptionNumbers.ID, Units.TITLE,
UnitOptionNumbers.OPTIONCOHORT
FROM UnitOptionNumbers INNER JOIN Units ON UnitOptionNumbers.ID = Units.ID WHERE
(((UnitOptionNumbers.NOAWARD)=Yes));
```

The most helpful error message I can get is:

```
[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

Which isn't helpful at all. I'm confident with mySQL, but I just cannot pinpoint the problem here. Please can you help me find the reason the query wont execute, or help me figure out a work around.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but perhaps it could be a problem with the fact that your table "test" has two fields with the same name ("TITLE")

Comment: Edited the question, I copied it wrong sorry, there are no duplicate fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425):
"This error occurs only with Microsoft Access when one of the column names specified in a select statement does not exist in the table being queried."

The solution therefore is to change

```
SELECT \"OPTION ONLY\" AS Expr
```

to

```
SELECT 'OPTION ONLY'
```

It seems the original code attempted to fill the first field with a default text value I.e "OPTION ONLY". "OPTION ONLY" was being read as a column name it seems.